# openinfowindowhtml on google map after retrieve information from server

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a google map in my site
and attach to it event handler of moveend

```
   GEvent.addListener(map, "moveend", function() 
    {
            map.clearovrelays();
            GetLayerDataFromServer(); //it set the markers again on the map  according the map position
    });
```

and also I have event handler for click on marker

```
GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function()
    { 
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml('this is the data');
    });
```

My problem is this

When user presses on one of the marker on the map 
it opens the 
openInfoWindowHtml  of the related marker.

And it also moves the map to that marker position.
And then it triggers the event

```
map.moveend
```

And in the event map.moveend I am clear all the marker on the map
and reload them according to the map new position.

The result is that 
When user clicks on marker it open for second his indoWindowHtml
and it clears the map and loads the markers again,
without showing the indoWindowHtml of the clicked marker.

My question is what shall I do in order to show the infoWindowHtml?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a flag that indicates if the user clicked a marker and not clear the map if that's the case.

```
var marker_clicked = false;

GEvent.addListener(map, "moveend", function() 
{
    if(!marker_clicked)
    {
        map.clearovrelays();
        GetLayerDataFromServer(); //it set the markers again on the map  acording the map position
    }
    marker_clicked = false;
});

GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function()
{
    marker_clicked = true;
    marker.openInfoWindowHtml('this is the data');
});
```

Comment: ok
but i want that  GetLayerDataFromServer
will occur because i want to get the markers for the map new coordinates

Comment: @avi: then move the GetLayerDataFromServer() outside the if clause.

Answer (score 0):

One possible alternative strategy is to open your info window with {suppressMapPan:true} which tells the map not to pan when the infowindow opens. That way, you know that any map movements are real map movements by the user.

Caution: {suppressMapPan:true} is undocumented, so it might possibly disappear in some future release.

Answer (score 0):

Another strategy would be to write

```
GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function()
    { 
        var iwAnchor = marker.getIcon().infoWindowAnchor;
        var iconAnchor = marker.getIcon().iconAnchor;
        var offset = new GSize(iwAnchor.x-iconAnchor.x,iwAnchor.y-iconAnchor.y);
        map.openInfoWindowHtml(marker.getLatLng(),'this is the data',{pixelOffset:offset});
    });
```

and then instead of calling clearOverlays(), loop through your markers one by one removing them.

By opening the infowindow on the map instead of the marker, it doesn't get automatically closed when the marker is removed.

The infowindow is now an overlay, so clearOverlays removes it, so you can't use clearOverlays. It might sound inefficient to loop through your markers, removing them one by one, but the clearOverlays does a very similar loop internally.

The iconAnchor calculations above simply position the infowindow in the same place that it would be if you had used marker.openInfowindowHtml, rather than at the foot of the marker.